# Administration pages incomplete after migrating from Drupal 6.28 to Drupal 7.2.2

Tags: drupal, migration, migrate

I have an error after migrating from Drupal 6.28 to Drupal 7.2.2.

I followed all migration steps from the UPGRADE.txt in the drupal 7.2.2 folder.

1- Updating modules and then disable.
2- Site in maintenance mode.
3- Change the theme to Garland
4- Remove all old core files and directories, except for the 'sites' directory and any custom files you added elsewhere
5- Run update.php (138 updates)

After this the site content appears to exist, but the admin pages are incomplete (URL below of what the page looks like). Because of this, the site is stuck maintenance mode.

All admin pages look like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4viev9vx3hgrum/admin_error.png

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I followed upgrade.txt to migrate a site from 6.x to 7.x! But then I realized its not 'complete'. There is only one way to migrate to higher core version -- Build all the features from scratch on higher version of Drupal and then import the content! This works in all cases!